# Image storing in sql server database using java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I am trying to save Image at SQL-SERVER Database using procedures .I have a PROCEDURE name with input parameters but I don't have procedure syntax.

```
BufferedImage imm = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\MY DATA\\Release 2\\18.jpg"));
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(imm, "jpg", baos );
baos.flush();
byte[] immAsBytes = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();

con.setAutoCommit(true);            
CallableStatement statement = con.prepareCall(query); 
ByteArrayInputStream baisForIndex2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(immAsBytes);
ByteArrayInputStream baisForIndex3 = new ByteArrayInputStream(immAsBytes);
statement.setDate(1, sqlDate);
statement.setBinaryStream(2, baisForIndex2, immAsBytes.length);
statement.setBinaryStream(3, baisForIndex3, immAsBytes.length);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

Error msg: Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with image.
SQLSTATE: S0002
Error code: 206
Error code: 0

What I want is compatible type of Java with IMAGE type of DB of sql-server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inserting a stream into a blob, the JDBC driver will read the specified length from it and will **not** reset the the stream when done.
In your example, you use this stream for placeholder 2, and then again for placeholder 3 and specify the entire length of the underlying byte[] each time. This way, when the driver gets to placeholder 3, the stream is exhausted, and cannot be read.

One solution could be to use two stream objects:

```
CallableStatement statement = con.prepareCall(query); 
ByteArrayInputStream baisForIndex2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(immAsBytes);
ByteArrayInputStream baisForIndex3 = new ByteArrayInputStream(immAsBytes);
statement.setDate(1, sqlDate);
statement.setBinaryStream(2, baisForIndex2, immAsBytes.length);
statement.setBinaryStream(3, baisForIndex3, immAsBytes.length);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks, This Worked. But I am still facing -"Error msg: Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with image SQLSTATE: S0002 Error code: 206 Error code: 0 " Issue.

Comment: Is the column data type in the underlying table nvarchar instead of varbinary?  If so, the column needs to be changed to varbinary.

Comment: Only I have is access of DB, I am not able to see db structure.
In this DB coloumn type is IMAGE.So what is compatible type for IMAGE in java code.